# Is it a good idea to have different forms share the same set of actions, reducer and even an api end point?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have two forms which have only one field difference between them. After submission the data is sent to an email address rather than stored in a database.

As you can imagine most of my actions and everything else including the back end server side handling of the submitted data is pretty much the same.

So I was wondering if it's a good idea to have forms share the same reducers, actions and even api endpoints, or should I create a different set for each form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO you should divide the form on separate reducers and have separate actions.
I would instead share with a single tone object API calls to endpoint.

Keeping your components well separated could simplify testing and better code maintainability specially when you need to add features later one in your development.